# Summing part of 2D array in python

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, append

I have a 2D array. After manipulating the x column of the array, I created a new 2D array (data2) with the new changes to the x column (and the y column remained the same). I now want to append the array of y values in data2 to a new array only if its x value is greater than 3 or less than 5. For example, if the 2D array was ([2,3], [4,5], [3.5,6], [9,7]), I would only want the y values of 5 and 6 in my new array because their x values are between 3 and 5. I'm stuck. please help!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('blah.txt') #blah.txt is a 2d array

c = (3*10)^8

x = c /((data[:,0])*10)

y = data[:,1]


data2 = np.array((x,y)).T

def new_yarray(data2):

    yarray =[]

    if data2[:,0] <= 5 or data2[:,0] >= 3:

        np.append(data2[:,1])

    print yarray

    return yarray
```

Comment: So did you manage to find a solution for the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner solution broken in several steps for clarity.

Given an array

```
>>> a
array([[ 2. ,  3. ],
       [ 4. ,  5. ],
       [ 3.5,  6. ],
       [ 9. ,  7. ]])
```

You can find the *index* of the elements where the `x` value is more than 3 and less than 5 by using `np.where()`:

```
>>> np.where(np.logical_and(a[:,0] > 3,a[:,0] < 5))
(array([1, 2]),)
```

Where `a[:,0] = array([ 2. ,  4. ,  3.5,  9. ])` is the array of all the `x` values. Now, you can get all the corresponding `y` values where `3 < x < 5` by:

```
>>> a[np.where(np.logical_and(a[:,0] > 3,a[:,0] < 5))][:,1]
array([ 5.,  6.])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to flatten the list and then append the values according.

```
def flatten_list(a, result=None):
    """ Flattens a nested list. """
    if result is None:
        result = []

    for x in a:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            flatten_list(x, result)
        else:
            result.append(x)
    return result

lst = ([2,3], [4,5], [3.5,6], [9,7])

lst = flatten_list(lst)

new_lst = []
for i in lst:
    if (float(i) > 3 and float(i) < 5):
        new_lst.append(i)
print new_lst
```

In this case, only 3.5 and 4 is greater than 3 and less 5...